# How do I install Xtreme Download Manager in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, download-manager

Since Ubuntu is very slow to download a file I would like to install Xtreme Download Manager for downloading. Please suggest me a way to install Xtreme Download Manager in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 28):

To install xtreme download manager in Ubuntu 14.04, please follow these steps

1. Open a terminal window.
2. Type in the following commands, then hit Enter after each:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps        
   sudo apt-get update        
   sudo apt-get install xdman
   ```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install xdman-downloader` for the latest version

Answer (score 0):

To download from the site [link](http://xdman.sourceforge.net/)

The **.tar** file downloaded need to be **extracted** and using terminal you can install the software.
Directions for installing are :

> cd /location of extracted folder/
>   cat readme.txt

In this file you can see the instructions for installation as per your linux Distros

Comment: @SurajJain By this way you can install any package on ubuntu

Comment: Just run in ternimal `sudo ./install.sh` in the extracted folder path. 
written in Readme.md file.

Answer (score 0):

To install the most latest stable version of Xtreme Download Manager on Ubuntu or on other Linux distributions, download the [XDM Linux installer](https://xtremedownloadmanager.com/#downloads) tar file, extract it and run the installer script to install it.

```
wget https://github.com/subhra74/xdm/releases/download/7.2.11/xdm-setup-7.2.11.tar.xz
tar -xvf xdm-setup-7.2.11.tar.xz
sudo sh install.sh
```