# Installing xtreme download manager via terminal

Tags: command-line, software-installation, permissions

I get this in terminal:

```
The directory '/home/elswerky/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/elswerky/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

What should I do?

Comment: The message you pasted has already said what you need to do. Did you try it?

Comment: what do you mean??
I want to know how to fix that terminal message,or whay should I do??

Comment: The title of your question suggests you're trying to install something, and presumably you are getting this message at some stage telling you how to fix some issue with it, so could you explain more clearly what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install xtreme download manager in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540054/how-do-i-install-xtreme-download-manager-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you wanted to install it via command line. Here it is

1. Download it first

   ```
   wget -c "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xdman/xdman.deb?r=https%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fxdman%2F&ts=1478419832&use_mirror=heanet" -O xdman.deb
   ```
2. Install it with dpkg

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i xdman.deb
   ```
3. Fix any dependency errors (if there is any)

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To install the most latest stable version of Xtreme Download Manager on Ubuntu or on other Linux distributions, download the [XDM Linux installer](https://xtremedownloadmanager.com/#downloads) tar file, extract it and run the installer script to install it.

```
wget https://github.com/subhra74/xdm/releases/download/7.2.11/xdm-setup-7.2.11.tar.xz
tar -xvf xdm-setup-7.2.11.tar.xz
sudo sh install.sh
```