# Can't install xdman using APT

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I tried to install xdman using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xdman
```

but I can't download it; I get this:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I get the same error if I try to install anything else.

After resolving that, I now get the error

```
E: unable to locate package xdman
```

[image: this is the new error I got]

Comment: The error as it says in temporary. most likely you system is checking for updates and 'beat' you to the lock (first in is first served..)   Check you don't have a question waiting, try again or better yet wait a few minutes and then try.  You can lock it yourself if you have one terminal doing updates, and then on another terminal try to 'update' a second time, but most likely it's just auto-updates.

Comment: i could download anything i want before i use sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps  after that i could download nothing.

Comment: I know this sounds like a cop-out, but something looks flaky with your network connection.  If you have the ability, I would try a different connection (coffee shop, friends wifi, etc) just to compare..

Answer (score 6):

I too have encountered this issue many times in my intial days of using Ubuntu (or similar distros)

To resolve your new issue, follow the steps as given below:

- Either download the setup file from this link - [Xdman Setup files](http://xdman.sourceforge.net/) 
  OR you can also use the wget command as - `wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/xdman/files/xdm-setup-x64.tar.xz` (if you are downloading x64 architecture)
- Once you have the setup file in tar.xz format, proceed to the next step of extraction. The command is - `tar -xvf xdm-setup-x64.tar.xz`

The step wise installation goes as follows:

```
$ wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/xdman/files/xdm-setup-x64.tar.xz

$ tar -xvf xdm-setup-x64.tar.xz
```

- As you execute the command, you can find the extracted folder in your home directory.
- Right click on folder name `xdman-setup` and select *Open in terminal*.
- Once you open the folder in terminal, simply enter - `sudo ./install.sh` to execute the script as root.

As soon as you execute the above command, you will see installation process will initiate on the terminal itself:

```
$ sudo ./install.sh
sudo: unable to resolve host mann
[sudo] password for tecjunkie: 
rm: cannot remove '/opt/xdman': No such file or directory
Initializing setup...
88939+0 records in
177878+0 records out
91073536 bytes (91 MB, 87 MiB) copied, 0.282047 s, 323 MB/s
Extracting files...
Installing...
Unpacking  /opt/xdman/jre//lib/charsets.pack...
Unpacking  /opt/xdman/jre//lib/ext/localedata.pack...
Unpacking  /opt/xdman/jre//lib/jsse.pack...
Unpacking  /opt/xdman/jre//lib/rt.pack...
Finishing installation...
Xtreme Download Manager installed successfully
You can start XDM from start menu, or type xdman in terminal as non root user
```

Once done, you can run xdman either from the start menu or you can also type `xdman` in the terminal.

As soon as you start, it will ask you to choose your browser to help you install add-on for xdman. Just follow in the process and you will then be able to download videos at ease.

Comment: it realy helped me thanks but when i try    $ ps -A | grep apt   it shows me nothing

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you. 
Mark the asnwer as correct solution so that even others can benefit from it. 

Thanks.

Comment: heres another problem :  sudo apt-get install xdman
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xdman
why does it says unbale to locate package xdman ? again it says the same thing when i want to install steam or telegram or chrome .. anything

Comment: can you please share a screenshot. 

Try the second answer in this link - https://askubuntu.com/questions/540054/how-do-i-install-xtreme-download-manager-in-ubuntu-14-04

The first answer is what you originally tried. May be the second answer given in the link resolves this issue.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/plarC.png

Comment: I have updated the link in my answer. Try if that solves your query of 'unable to locate package'. 
 
Follow the steps in the updated link and I believe it will resolve this isse 
as well. 

Waiting for status update.

Comment: ok review team. allow me to update my answer with caution and screenshots if possible. May be then it will be marked as right and proves beneficial to one and all

Comment: Thank you @DavidFoerster sir. I have revised my answer with proper commands and screenshot. Do let me know if there is anything that I need to change. 

I will definitely take account of what you taught me and I will ensure I follow this practice in future if applicable. 

Regards.

Comment: I have personally installed xdman on my system @DavidFoerster sir. Let me paste its intallation process (happening via terminal) as normal text here. 

May be then it will be much heplful.

Comment: I have pasted the entire xdman installation process (happening in terminal) in Block quote format @DavidFoerster  sir. 

Let me know if the answer is now good to go. I look forward to your guidance.

Regards.

Comment: @mAnN you don't need to have the *output* of `wget` or the *output* of commands you're going to rub.  You only need to list the **specific commands** to execute, and not their output.

Comment: point noted @ThomasWard sir. Will ensure I implement your feedback at all places.

Thank you for guiding me.

Comment: this worked even in ubuntu  19.04